# Pip install python-tds error code 1

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am trying to install python-tds and I cannot figure out where to go from here. I have very limited experience with python so any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You need superuser privileges to do so. Try with: $ `sudo pip install python-tds`

Comment: wow that worked perfectly thank you, any chance you can give me some insight as to why i needed the "sudo"?

Comment: Updated the answer with that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install a package that will need to write files under system directories and your [current] user does not have enough privileges to do so:

```
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytds': Permission denied
```

You need to install it as superuser:

```
$ sudo pip install python-tds
```

In this particular case, `sudo` will elevate the privileges (to superuser) for the command *in front of it*. `sudo` may also be used to execute any command as any other existing user (`$ man sudo` for more information).